# Define bar chart colors for Pandas/Matplotlib with defined column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have a dataframe "table" like this:

`SAMPLE   RANK   VALUE
 CAT       3      N
 DOG       1      N
 FISH      4      Y
 ANT       2      N
 HORSE     5      N`

How can I JUST COLOR the 3rd histogram column, given that there is a "Y" in the VALUE column? I would like it to look like this:

So far I have :

`table.plot('SAMPLE','RANK', hue="VALUE", palette={"Y": "r", "N": '0.75'}, kind='bar')`

but this does not work

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may achieve the desired effect by mapping `VALUE` column to desired colors:

```
colors = {'N':'#00BEC5', 'Y':'#F9746A'}
df.sort_values('RANK', inplace=True)
df.plot.bar(x='SAMPLE', y='RANK',color= df['VALUE'].map(colors));
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you!