# Colors for pandas bar chart

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, colors

[Note] This question has poped up several times already, but does not seem to have a fix that works with the current versions. Both solutions mentioned in  [Define bar chart colors for pandas matplotlib with defined column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044866/define-bar-chart-colors-for-pandas-matplotlib-with-defined-column/) and in [Matplotlib Bar Chart choose color if value is positive vs value is negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311139/matplotlib-bar-chart-choose-color-if-value-is-positive-vs-value-is-negative) do not work anymore

I want to plot a dataframe with bars and assign colors based on the value. All values below a threshold should be red, above green.

My dataframe looks something like this:
A is the index, '%' the only column

```
   A      %
--------------
   a      1
   b      10
   c      50
   d      80
```

I want everything below 50 to be red, the rest blue. The dataframe is already in the right ascending order.

I have tried the dictionary solution for the colors described above (with adding an additional column), with no success; also a few other solutions like dividing the df into two dataframes (one with values above threshold, one with values below).

Just trying to cycle through a list of different colors does not seem to work:

```
df.plot(kind = 'bar', ax=axes3, color = ['r', 'g', 'b'])
```

all the columns come out red here.

I have tried the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22311139/4284627), by adding a column 'colors' differentiating the values between 'red' and 'blue'.

```
   A      %    colors
--------------
   a      1     red
   b      10    red
   c      50    blue
   d      80    blue
```

and I added this to my code:

```
 color = df.colors.map({'red': 'r', 'blue': 'b'})
```

still, all my columns are red.

Comment: Try this I have made 2 columns df['Test'] = np.where(df.Percentage < 50,df.Percentage,50)  df['diff'] = df.Percentage - df.Test then try to plot df[['Test','diff']].plot.bar(stacked=True).It gives the result. @Moiraine24

Comment: The solution in [the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311139/matplotlib-bar-chart-choose-color-if-value-is-positive-vs-value-is-negative) works perfectly fine. If you have a problem, provide a [mcve].