# Problems assigning color to bars in Pandas v0.20 and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am struggling for a while with the definition of colors in a bar plot using Pandas and Matplotlib. Let us imagine that we have following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
pers1 = ["Jesús","lord",2]
pers2 = ["Mateo","apostel",1]
pers3 = ["Lucas","apostel",1]
    
dfnames = pd.DataFrame(
    [pers1,pers2, pers3],
    columns=["name","type","importance"]
)
```

Now, I want to create a bar plot with the importance as the numerical value, the names of the people as ticks and use the type column to assign colors. I have read other questions (for example: [Define bar chart colors for Pandas/Matplotlib with defined column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044866/define-bar-cahart-colors-for-pandas-matplotlib-with-defined-column)) but it doesn't work...

So, first I have to define colors and assign them to different values:

```
colors = {'apostel':'blue','lord':'green'}
```

And finally use the .plot() function:

```
dfnames.plot(
    x="name",
    y="importance",
    kind="bar",
    color = dfnames['type'].map(colors)
)
```

Good. The only problem is that all bars are green:

[image]

Why?? I don't know... I am testing it in Spyder and Jupyter... Any help? Thanks!

Comment: What is your pandas version? I haven't tested this but if I remember correctly, there was a bug related to this.

Comment: Works for me on 0.19.1

Comment: 0.20.3. I guess I should update?

Comment: @José I've mentioned two alternatives. Please try the second one and let me know whether it works or not, before updating. Thanks.

Comment: You were right, it was a bug. I tend to think that the problem is in my code, of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per this [GH16822](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16822), this is a ***regression bug*** introduced in version `0.20.3`, wherein only the *first* colour was picked from the list of colours passed. This was not an issue with prior versions.

The reason, according to one of the contributors was this -

> The problem seems to be in `_get_colors`. I think that `BarPlot` should
>   define a `_get_colors` that does something like
>
> ```
> def _get_colors(self, num_colors=None, color_kwds='color'):
>     color = self.kwds.get('color')
>     if color is None:
>         return super()._get_colors(self, num_colors=num_colors, color_kwds=color_kwds)
>     else:
>         num_colors = len(self.data)  # maybe? may not work for some cases
>         return _get_standard_colors(color=kwds.get('color'), num_colors=num_colors)
> ```

---

There's a couple of options for you -

1. The most obvious choice would be to update to the latest version of pandas (currently `v0.22`)
2. If you need a workaround, there's one (also mentioned in the issue tracker) whereby you wrap the arguments within an extra tuple -

   ```
   dfnames.plot(x="name",  
                y="importance", 
                kind="bar", 
                color=[tuple(dfnames['type'].map(colors))]
   ```

Though, in the interest of progress, I'd recommend updating your pandas.

Answer (score 2):

I find another solution to your problem and it works!

I used directly matplotlib library instead of using plot attribute of the data frame :
here is the code :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline # for jupyter notebook

pers1 = ["Jesús","lord",2]
pers2 = ["Mateo","apostel",1]
pers3 = ["Lucas","apostel",1]

dfnames = pd.DataFrame([pers1,pers2, pers3], columns=["name","type","importance"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars = ax.bar(dfnames.name, dfnames.importance)


colors = {'apostel':'blue','lord':'green'}

for index, bar in enumerate(bars) :
    color = colors.get(dfnames.loc[index]['type'],'b') # get the color key in your df
    bar.set_facecolor(color[0])
plt.show()
```

And here is the results :

[image]